# Can't build using x code. Got "10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, architecture

Trying to build iPhone version of my game in unity. when trying to build on Xcode I got a lot of errors. Are there any settings I'm missing on unity before build?
Anyway now after some tries I'm getting this error: "10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"
I searched hours for a solution. nothing work. I notice that some suggest the problem with .m files but I don't know what I can do.
I think that the .m are the problem because I count 10 of them exactly as the error.

Thank you

I try to clean build and uninstall and install cocoapods